# Add module .C to linux kernel

Tags: linux, gcc, module, kernel

good afternoon, I have a problem and I could not solve it, I try to add a .c module to the linux kernel, it's just a .c file called
Stealth.c I have tried to find guides on how to add it step by step but I can not find it by any means, I am not very familiar with the kernel,

thanks for your help

Comment: Stack Overflow neither helps to locate *guides* on other resources nor creates guides (except ones on [SO documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation)). You may start with documentation shipped with kernel sources. E.g. using one at [Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt) you may understand how to add source file into the kernel build process.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you put this file is somewhere in your kernel source tree, the directory it's in should have a `Makefile`. Add the line

`obj-y += Stealth.o`

If you want to deal with configuration, you'll probably want to add the object file to `obj-$(CONFIG_WHATEVER)` instead of `obj-y`, but I won't be going into how to add a configuration here.

If you're looking to compile your file as an external module, a quick google search pops http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x181.html which seems good enough.